# Create new column using multiple groupby's in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have a dataset where I would like to:

1. group by location and box and take a count of the box

### Data

```
ID  location    type    box     status          
aa  NY          no      box55   hey         
aa  NY          no      box55   hi          
aa  NY          yes     box66   hello           
aa  NY          yes     box66   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box11   hey         
aa  CA          no      box11   hi          
aa  CA          yes     box11   hello           
aa  CA          yes     box11   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box86   hey         
aa  CA          no      box86   hi          
aa  CA          yes     box86   hello           
aa  CA          yes     box99   goodbye         
aa  CA          no      box99   hey         
aa  CA          no      box99   hi
```

### Desired

```
location    box count   box     
NY          2           box55   
NY          2           box66   
CA          3           box11   
CA          3           box86   
CA          3           box99
```

### Doing

```
df['box count'] = df.groupby(['location','box'])['box'].size()
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: and what is wrong to your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.groupby(["location", "box"], as_index=False).agg(
    **{"box count": ("box", "size")}
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  location    box  box count
0       CA  box11          4
1       CA  box86          3
2       CA  box99          3
3       NY  box55          2
4       NY  box66          2
```

---

EDIT:

```py
m = df.groupby(["location"])["box"].nunique()
df = df.groupby(["location", "box"], as_index=False).agg(
    **{
        "box count": (
            "location",
            lambda x: m[x.iat[0]],
        )
    }
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  location    box  box count
0       CA  box11          3
1       CA  box86          3
2       CA  box99          3
3       NY  box55          2
4       NY  box66          2
```

Comment: Hi @Andrej the 4 should be a 3 right? We are saying there are 3 distinct boxes in CA location (box11, box86 and box99)